# Images are not loading from amazon s3

Tags: amazon-s3, loading

I have come across a weird problem.

I have moved some files to amazon s3.
I can see those files using cloud berry but some of them are not loading.
I have given the below settings.

```
hedaers: cache-control
value:  public,max-age=8640000
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Isn't hedaers suppose to be headers?

Comment: that is fine, that is given manually using cloudberry. so i don't have to type header there.